# SFML blending mode to interpolate colors with alpha

Tags: c++, colors, sfml, alphablending, blending

Assume I have a `C_1 = (255, 0, 0, 127)` filled `sf::Texture` and a `sf::RenderTexture` filled with  `C_2 = (0, 0, 0, 0)`. Then I call

```
render_texture.draw(texture);
```

The result given by `sf::BlendAlpha` is a texture filled with `(127, 0, 0, 127)`, but my goal (for the small graphics editor app I'm writing) is blending those two colors to get `(255, 0, 0, 127)`, because, intuitively, drawing on perfectly transparent texture is "copying color of your brush to it". I've checked formulas of `sf::BlendAlpha`, and it appeared to work like this:

```
C_res = C_src * aplha_src + C_dst * (1 - alpha_src)
```

Where `C_src` is `C_1` and `C_dst` is `C_2`. But wait, does it totally ignore aplha_dst?

If I understand blending right, the formula I need is something like

```
alpha_sum = alppha_src + alpha_dst
C_res = C_src * alpha_src / alpha_sum + C_dst * alpha_dst / alpha_sum
```

Which gives adequate colors and does not ignore `alpha_dst`. But with BlendingMode from SFML, using different Factors and Equations, there's no chance to get division (that also introduces troubles when dealing with `alpha_sum = 0`). Any suggestions on how actually I should think about blending colors and painting? At least, did I get it right, that usual alpha blending used by SFML is not what graphics editors do? (tested on Aseprite, Krita, Photoshop, they blend color from the brush to `(0, 0, 0, 0)` as I expect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up with: writing your own blend mode with glsl and using shaders. This way you can create and formulas without the need to think about how to bring it to sfml, because it already supports shaders, that can be easily passed to any draw call.